# ¿Cómo asignar archivo en mi servidor a variable de tipo imagen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Desarrollo una aplicación WebApi en la cual debo insertar en una tabla de  la  DB SqlServer una foto en un campo de tipo `Image` , todo esta bien hasta que en la solicitud del cliente este campo lo recibo vació (es decir desde la aplicación cliente no envían una imagen), en este caso en mi aplicación se genera un error `SqlException` el procedimiento almacenado `Sp_InsertarProductor` esta esperando el parámetro  `@Foto` el cual no se ha especificado...

Entonces lo que quiero hacer en ese caso es asignar a la variable una  imagen que esta en una carpeta dentro de mi servidor …

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Mi Procedimiento Almacenado :

```
    USE [FloraNueva]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_InsertarPrueba] (@IDENTIFICADOR UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),@EDAD INT, @ESTADO VARCHAR(50),@FOTO IMAGE) 
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO  TABLAPRUEBA (IDENTIFICADOR,NOMBRE,EDAD,ESTADO,FOTO) VALUES(@IDENTIFICADOR,@NOMBRE,@EDAD,@ESTADO,@FOTO);
    END
```

Mi Aplicación :

```
 public int InsertarPrueba(Productor P)
            {
                int resultado = new int();
                SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
                using (Conexion)
                {
                    Conexion.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Sp_InsertarPrueba", Conexion);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identificador", P.Id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", P.Nombre);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", P.Edad);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", P.Estado);
                    if (Foto == null)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOTO", ObtenerImagenNoDisponible());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FOTO", ImageToByteArray(P.Foto));
                    }
                    resultado = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Conexion.Close();
                }
                return resultado;
            }

public static Image ObtenerImagenNoDisponible()
            {
               //AQUI CODIGO QUE ME FALTA
            }


   public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No sería mejor editar el SP? Si lo que quieres es evitar ese error, un IF Statement en el SP preguntando si la variable es nula, la ignoras y si tiene datos, la insertas.

Comment: y como hago eso ? fredyfx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar llenar la BD de imágenes "No disponible", insertas en la BD dependiendo si hay foto o no.

```
USE [FloraNueva]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_InsertarPrueba] (@IDENTIFICADOR UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @NOMBRE VARCHAR(50), @EDAD INT, @ESTADO VARCHAR(50), @FOTO IMAGE)
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF @FOTO IS NULL--# Aqui esta la verificación...
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO  TABLAPRUEBA (IDENTIFICADOR, NOMBRE, EDAD, ESTADO)VALUES(@IDENTIFICADOR, @NOMBRE, @EDAD, @ESTADO); 
        END 
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO  TABLAPRUEBA (IDENTIFICADOR, NOMBRE, EDAD, ESTADO, FOTO)VALUES(@IDENTIFICADOR, @NOMBRE, @EDAD, @ESTADO, @FOTO); 
    END
END
```

Y cuando vayas a mostrar la información, si el campo `FOTO` está nulo, llamas a "la foto by default":

```
public static Image ObtenerImagenNoDisponible()
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Recurso/Foto.jpg"));
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Cambie la ubicacion de la imagen a una carpeta de nombre Recurso en mi proyecto
2. El metodo lo escribi de esta manera

   ```
   public static Image ObtenerImagenNoDisponible()
   {
       Image img = Image.FromFile(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Recurso/Foto.jpg"));
       return img;
   }
   ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vas a llenar espacio en la BD...